# Documentation for array globbing

Tags: perl

Where does perldoc mention array inside diamond `perl -MO=Deparse -e '<@r>'`

```
use File::Glob ();
glob(join($", @r));
```

which is roughly `glob("@r")`?

Comment: Not sure, but here's what `<>` does: If it's empty, it means `readline(ARGV)`. If what's inside looks like a file handle, then `<HANDLE>` means `readline(HANDLE)`. Otherwise, `<EXPR>` means `glob(qq<EXPR>)`.

Comment: @ikegami yes, but this explicit join looked strange, I was expecting something like `perl -MO=Deparse -e 'glob "@r"'`

Comment: Deparse can't tell the difference between the two.

Comment: No, that's not true. There's one tiny difference that allows it to differentiate (`diff <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'"@r"' 2>&1 ) <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'join($", @r)' 2>&1 )`), and it uses that very difference to differentiate between `$a.$b` and `"$a$b"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It treats it like standard variable interpolation inside a double quoted string.

And then it works as [`perldoc glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) says in the 2nd paragraph.

> Note that glob splits its arguments on whitespace and treats each segment as separate pattern.

So it becomes equivalent to

```
map <$_>, @r
```